# I have problem with reading data conditionally based on checkbox

Tags: javascript, c#, ajax, kendo-ui

I want to read data (KENDO datasource) conditionally based on checkbox with `id = 'ShowAdvanced'`, but when i try to read if it is checked, kendo shows: undefined => Controller always get false

```
dataSource: {
            autoSync: false,
            transport: {
                read: {
                    url: "/Servis/InstalovaneKomponentyData",
                    data: {
                        'ShowValidOnly': function (e) {
                            if ($('#ShowAdvanced').checked)
                                return false;
                            else
                                return true;
                        }
                    },
                    dataType: "json"
                },
...
```

Comment: I don't think `data: { 'ShowValidOnly': function (e) { ` is valid and would work. You can filter data by a checkbox's value, but I believe it is not that way.

Answer (score 1):

You are evaluating the checked property incorrectly using jQuery.

Using jQuery, evaluate the checked state using

```
$("#ShowAdvanced").is(":checked")
```

or

```
$("#ShowAdvanced").prop("checked")
```

not

```
$('#ShowAdvanced').checked
```

like you currently are.

Using plain javascript you evaluate the state using

```
document.getElementById("ShowAdvanced").checked
```

So, you are currently using a jQuery selector to get the checkbox but incorrectly using the plain JS .checked to get the state.

[Example](https://dojo.telerik.com/@Stephen/AjUPOGUD)